# Tileset ID and Source layer not centering map on India in Power BI with Mapbox

Tags: mapbox-studio

When I copy and paste the Tileset ID, Source layer and field into Power BI with Mapbox installed it does not show the map centered on India. It only shows the world map. I have tried this using Mapbox in Power BI.

I tried out as in the documentation of Mapbox but it is not working.